# How do I attach a variable to a QTextEdit control

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QTextEdit control on a GUI.  I want to link it to a control in the same way I do in C# or MFC but cannot quite find the command.

Essentially I have this:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QString fileName_;

    QMap<QString, unsigned int> vars_; // this is the data I want to associate
};
```

and in the ui::MainWindow class I have:

```
class Ui_MainWindow
{
public:
    QWidget *centralWidget;
    QTextEdit *ALU;       // this is the control I want to associate with the data
.
.
.
```

I am sure that this is trivial but I cannot see how to associate an instance of the map with the GUI control.

Am I being blind or does Qt use a different pattern?

Comment: What do you mean by link? Do you want to store a reference to `vars_` inside `ALU`?

Comment: I just want to bind one of the map values to the control such that when I update the control the value in the variable changes and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `QTextEdit::textChanged()` signal.

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0) : QMainWindow(parent)
    {
        connect(ALU, SIGNAL(textChanged()), this, SLOT(updateVars()));
        ...
    }

private slots:
    void updateVars()
    {
        // do something with vars_
    }
};
```

Comment: This is good in that it stores the value of the control to the variable, it there an automated way I can instantly update the GUI is the variable changes in the background?

Comment: There is no "out of the box" solution. You can write a simple class that inherits `QObject` with `vars_` inside and emit `changed()` signal whenever you update `vars_`. You can also use `QTimer` to check `vars_` for changes periodically. But all these would be an overkill probably.

Comment: Oh, that is a shame.  Never mind, I will redesign the code and do it a different way.  Thanks for the help!